# Load en.yml before config.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

I work on Ruby on Rails application. For some reason I need to translate some values from my **config.yml** file. Here it is (simplified it to make short and readable):

```
foo:
 bar: <%= I18n.t 'config.foo.bar' %>
```

In my **en.yml**:

```
---
en:
  config:
    foo:
      bar: "Translated bar"
```

But when I'm trying to start server, it shows the error message:

```
translation missing: en.config.foo.bar
```

I guess this happens because **config.yml** loads before any of my files with translations (including **en.yml**). I have alot of translations in over places and they work fine. Any ideas how can I force **en.yml** to load before **config.yml**? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the order of parsing init scripts: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html